# What is the difference between mouseover & onmouseover in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, mouseover, onmouseover

I am a novice JavaScript programmer. Can someone make me understand how this works?

What is the difference between `mouseover` & `onmouseover` in JavaScript? Can we interchange its use? If not, how do we know which one to use where?

`mouseover` example:

```
function showAlert() {}
button.addEventListener('mouseover', showAlert);
```

`onmouseover` example:

```
function changeColor() {} 
titleHeader.onmouseover = changeColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically both of them is same according to what they do , but the differences arises when we talk about what the do. you can use anyone out of them as per your wish but the addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions which is required when you want to use mouseover.
Syntax of addEventListener() which is dom element is
addEventListener(event, function)

event(required)-> A String that specifies the name of the event.
Note : Do not use the "on" prefix. For example, use "mouseover" instead of "mouseover".
function(required)->Specifies the function to run when the event occurs.
eg:

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a "mouseover" and "mouseout" event to a h1 element.</p>

    <h1 id="demo">Mouse over me</h1>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
    function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
**Dom Event onmouseover**
    <body>
    <h1 id="demo">Mouse over me</h1>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").onmouseover = function(){mouseOver()};

    function mouseOver() {
     document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
    }
    </script>
    </body>
```

At last I will like to add that you can use addEventListener inside script only you cant use it inside your html body howerver in case of Dom event you can use it inside html also using syntax like 
Eg:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>This example demonstrates how to assign an "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" 
    event to a h1 element.</p>
    <h1 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()" >Mouse over me</h1>
    <script>
    function mouseOver() {
     document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I believe there is some mistyping in the 2nd para. Please can you confirm this?

Comment: no its correctly typed you can ask your doubt then i would try to resolve that

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. I was just getting confused about this part: In the 2nd para, it reflects, 'Do not use the "on" prefix. For example, use "mouseover" instead of "mouseover".'